# Релиз и Дебаг версия java web приложений

Tags: java, maven, веб-сервер

Задача следующая. Есть приложение на java с web. Есть некий корневой контекст для него.

jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 5.0//EN"
        "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_5_0.dtd">
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>main-root</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Проект собирается мавеном.

Необходимо сделать две версии данного приложения Дебаг и Релиз. И у них должны быть разные корневые контексты. Грубо говоря запускаем сборку, получаем DEBUG.war, запускаем другую сборку, получаем RELEASE.war.

Как это правильно принято делать? (У меня есть предположение что необходимо мавен с параметрами запускать, а он например будет как то переопределять содержимое jboss-web.xml)

Comment: а в чем принципиальная разница между собранными war?

Comment: Пока что только разные корневые контекст должны быть. Может потом еще что то появится, но пока только так. я уже сделал сейчас через профайлы и  maven-war-plugin. Активирую или нет профайл и в плагине добавляю один из двух вариантов файла jboss-web.xml  в WEB-INF. Вроде работает, но выглядит как костыль. Вот я и думал есть ли некие стандартные способы для всего этого

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что мавеном это будет просто сделать. Всё что приходит в голову навскидку плагин assembly и maven profile. Профайлом будешь задавать режим сборки.
Но на самом деле советую сменить мавен на gradle или крайний случай ant.